# How To Run a Flutter Web Application Offline?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web, wpa

I got a problematic assignment from my employers.
I was given the task of developing simple software that will run strictly on Google Chrome,
**without attempting to connect to the web** (Security reasons).

I know flutter development and I feel comfortable with the sdk.
How should I develop a web app that can be deployed using a usb stick?
Looks like PWA can be an option, but the documentation is lacking in detail.

- The system does not have the ability to run a local web server.
- The Flutter app must be able to work with JS libraries, I intend to use jsQR.

Comment: Have you find a solution in the meantime? I'm struggling with a very similar issue

Answer (score 1):

service workers and indexedDB could help you for develop offline route app and offline api.

[mdn docs for service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this will fit your particular case: you say that the system can't run a local webserver, but what if you provide the webserver along with your software?

I just discovered `get_server`: you can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/get_server). It aims to allow developers to host their own HTTP server by using only flutter, without resorting to external tools or other coding/scripting languages. It allows also (and that's the relevant part) to wrap your flutter web app and make it run on local network.

For now I only tried with a very simple example, but it seems to be working. These are the steps I took:

- create a new flutter project: since I needed the webserver to run on Windows, I had to get flutter ready for that (see [here](https://flutter.dev/desktop) for help)
- add `get_server` to the new pubspec.yaml
- run `flutter build web` on your flutter web project, and copy the `build/web` output
  folder in the root folder of the new project (I renamed the folder while copying since flutter might change the content of the `web` folder)
- delete all the content of `lib/main.dart`
- paste this (this the actual content of `main.dart`)

  ```
  import 'package:get_server/get_server.dart' as gs;
  void main() {
    gs.runApp(
      gs.GetServerApp(home: gs.FolderWidget('folderName')),
    );
  }
  ```

`folderName` is the name of the renamed folder containing the flutter web app build.

I ran this on Windows 'device' from AndroidStudio, and my original flutter web app was reachable at `localhost:8080` (for now I just used the default options of `get_server`). I also got the webserver (empty) GUI as a white window: I guess that can be useful for some information regarding the server itself, although, if that windows closes, `localhost:8080` becomes unavailable.
But, once released, you should be able to just run the executable from the USB stick, and then connect to it with Chrome.

PS: after some time using GetServer, I had to switch to other packages because of not-so-good docs and support. Now I'm using [shelf](https://github.com/dart-lang/shelf), but also [Alfred](https://github.com/rknell/alfred) is a notable mention.

Comment: Did you manage to run your flutter web app using shelf or alfred? Would you mind sharing?

Comment: @EricSu Yes, I got it working with `shelf`: I'll probably post a new question or answer so I can put all the code in it. I'll let you know when I'm done.

Comment: @EricSu I created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74774859/hosting-a-web-server-in-a-local-enviroment-using-only-flutter/)